# Compare two tables and find not matched price SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table #tmp1
( 
     name varchar(100),
     price decimal(10, 2)
)

insert into #tmp1 values('Test', 200.00)
insert into #tmp1 values('Test', 100.00)
insert into #tmp1 values('Test', 300.00)
insert into #tmp1 values('Test1', 500.00)
insert into #tmp1 values('Test2', 300.00)

create table #tmp
(
     name varchar(100),
     price decimal(10,2)
)

insert into #tmp values('Test', 200.00)
insert into #tmp values('Test', 100.00)
insert into #tmp values('Test', 400.00)
insert into #tmp values('Test1', 600.00)
insert into #tmp values('Test3', 300.00)
```

I have two tables with comparing parameter Name and find not matched price.
Name should match and price will be differ.

Expected output:

```
Name    Price       Price
------------------------------
Test1   600.00      500.00
Test    300.00      400.00
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: sql server, select * from #tmp a,#tmp1 b
where a.name=b.name  but price should be differ

Comment: What would happen if you have another unmatched records of test1 in each table? how would you know to join?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thank you for your information, hereafter i never use old style joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM #tmp a
INNER JOIN #tmp1 b ON a.name=b.name AND a.PRICE <> b.PRICE
```

**UPDATED** : AS per your below comment you wants to consider order of insertion as well,

```
;WITH tmp AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) RN    
  FROM #tmp 
),tmp1 AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) RN    
  FROM #tmp1 
)
SELECT a.name,a.price,b.price
FROM tmp a
INNER JOIN tmp1 b ON a.name=b.name AND a.RN=b.RN  AND a.PRICE <> b.PRICE
```